# Outlook REST API - How to get In-Reply-To header

Tags: outlook-restapi, outlook-api

I found this thread: [Office 365 Rest API read the In-Reply-To field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074374/office-365-rest-api-read-the-in-reply-to-field), but there is no follow up on what happened with this request (or at least I can't find any).
I need to know what is the In-Reply-To header for a reply Draft message, so I can send it through the API.

Comment: I found a thread that answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103388/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-rfc-2822-or-any-headers-from-an-email-with-the